# How to render twig content from database (overwrite render function)?

Tags: symfony, twig

For several reasons i stored some twig templates in my database (twig path + html markup).

I want to achieve the following:

When i call the render function in my controller (extends Controller), i want the database to be checked first to see if there is a template, otherwise it returns the twig template as usual.

However, because I have 50 controllers, overriding the render function would be best, so my call stays the same:

```
return $this->render('@testfrontend/MyAccount/index.html.twig');
```

Comment: What have you've tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: To be honest, I'm currently out of ideas. with all the solutions that i found, i would have to adjust the call of the render-function, i.e. around 50 controllers.

Comment: You should create a new class extending the Symfony `AbstractController`, then override the `renderView` method, and make your controllers to extend your own class. It can be done easily with modern IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@VincentDecaux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999617/vincent-decaux)

> You should create a new class extending the Symfony
> AbstractController, then override the renderView method, and make your
> controllers extend your own class. It can be done easily with modern
> IDE.

On a more granular level,

- the official documentation shows how to Customize Form Rendering,
  https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html
- Overriding a custom theme template https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227268/how-do-i-override-theme-custom-twig-in-my-module-to-render-input-fields